# Erro de compilação usando classe AudioPlayer

Tags: java

Ao tentar compilar o código abaixo:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import sun.audio.*;
import com.sun.java.util.*; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class filechus {
    public static void main(String[]args) {

        JFrame tela = new JFrame("Telex"); 
        JFileChooser filex = new JFileChooser();

        int opcao = filex.showOpenDialog(tela);

        if (opcao==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
            File nomearquivo = filex.getSelectedFile();
            try {
                InputStream arq = new FileInputStream(nomearquivo); 
                AudioStream som = new AudioStream(arq); 
                AudioPlayer.player.start(som); 
                System.out.println("Tocando");
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Deu erro");
            }
        }
        tela.setBounds(10,10,800,600);
        tela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        tela.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> AudioPlayer is internal proprietary api and may be removed in a future release

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Qual o erro que está dando? Podia detalhar mais a pergunta?

Comment: Saudações, acontece que quando eu compilo, o mesmo da o seguinte erro: audio player is internal proprietary api and may be removed in a future release

Comment: Isso é um erro mesmo ou é só um aviso (*warning*)? O programa termina de compilar e executa?

Comment: Isto é um (warning), mas o programa não acabava de complicar, até terem me dado a solução abaixo, pelo @Victor.

Answer (score 3):

O seu problema está nos imports:

```java
import sun.audio.*;
import com.sun.java.util.*;
```

Os pacotes `sun.*`, `sunw.*` e `com.sun.*` são pacotes proprietários e internos da JDK que não devem ser utilizados por aplicações, por isso que o seu compilador reclama deles. No meu caso pelo menos, o pacote `com.sun.java.util` nem sequer existe.

Para arrumar isso, consegui fazendo uso das classes do pacote `javax.sound.sampled`:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class filechus {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        JFrame tela = new JFrame("Telex");
        JFileChooser filex = new JFileChooser();
        int opcao = filex.showOpenDialog(tela);
        if (opcao == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
            File nomearquivo = filex.getSelectedFile();

            try {
                InputStream arq = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(nomearquivo));
                AudioInputStream som = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(arq);
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(som);
                clip.start();
                System.out.println("Tocando");
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        tela.setBounds(10,10,800,600);
        tela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        tela.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Observe também que ao tratar o erro, é importante que o programa ao menos te informe qual foi o erro que deu para te ajudar a solucioná-lo.

Comment: Saudações, obrigado pela ajuda dada, complicou sem erros, nem avisos.

Comment: @AugustoTomás Complicou ou compilou?

Comment: Compilou, desculpa o erro de dicionário, Victor

Comment: @AugustoTomás Ok, então. Não se esquece de dar o aceite na minha resposta caso não lhe reste mais nenhuma dúvida. :)

Comment: até ao momento está era a minha inquietação. Obrigado pela ajuda.